# Vector Loop not functioning properly

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, vector

I'm trying to write a program that takes 10 people who ate pancakes, and returns the person who ate the most pancakes, I'm using vectors in order to create new elements as the user enters it and return them later, I tried using an array but I was having a harder time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std ; 

int main()
{
    int  lnum , input ;
    int temp = 0;
    vector <int> persons(10) ;

    cout << "This program takes input for 10 people who ate pancakes, \
        then checks who   ate the most pancakes " << endl;

    cout << "Enter the amount of pancakes each person ate: " << endl ;
    cout << "Person 1: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << "Person 2: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << "Person 3: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << "Person 4: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << "Person 5: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << "Person 6: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << "Person 7: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << "Person 8: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << "Person 9: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << "Person 10: " ; 
    cin >> input ;
    persons.push_back(input);
    cout << endl ;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 11; i++){
        if(persons.at(i) > temp){
            temp == persons.at(i) ; 
        }
    }

    cout << temp << endl ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Mostly everything runs fine, except when I run the program, it returns temp as 0, instead of what the actual number should be. Also when I call commands like

```
person.at(1) ;
```

it returns the incorrect value, what I am doing wrong, is this a logical error or syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace this entire section:

```
for(int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) // note the non-hard-coded conditional
{
    if(persons.at(i) > temp)
    {
        temp = persons.at(i); // note fixed to assignment! 
    }
}
```

with

```
temp = std::max_element(persons.begin(), persons.end());
```

Comment: Thank you, I was aware that there might be an easy approach to the finding the largest number but I still wanted to use the manual approach in order to get better. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you're initializing your vector incorrectly:

```
vector <int> persons; // Vector will resize automatically
```

Then, try `=` instead of `==`, and change the limits of your loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < persons.size(); i++){
    if(persons.at(i) > temp){
        temp = persons.at(i); // Assignment, not comparison
    }
}
```

See @ZacHowland's answer for a much easier way to find the maximum element of a `vector`.

Comment: it returns 0 for some reason.

Comment: When I initialized the vector like that, the program crashed. ://

Comment: @BryanFajardo That's because the limits of your `for` loop were incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
temp == persons.at(i) ;
```

does not assign the value of persons[i] to temp. It compares the two values, then the boolean result is dropped.

You probably meant a single `=`.

Comment: tried it, I had actually tried that first and switched it to see if maybe that's what the issue was. Both of are not working.